# Hide 'OFF' Button in Dropdown or make it a separate Button

Tags: dropdown, toggle

[image]
Everything in one Dropdown or a separate binary-Button to activate Dropdown choice.
The latter one requires more clicks and mouse movement but somehow feels better to me. What do you think?

Sorry if something similar has been asked before, couldn't find it. Will remove this if someone gives me a similar link.

Edit: Or even none of the 2 above, if you have a better idea.

Comment: In the example given, you'd be better off woth a Radio Button group: Weekly, Monthly, No Thanks. Only one way to know which way works best for your users and that is to ask them, or do A-B Tests as a proxy.

Answer (score 3):

Hiding it in the dropdown feels like a [dark pattern](https://darkpatterns.org/) - the user would have to open up the dropdown to see the option to not be subscribed. I'd say it's better to have a clear "on/off" button as the primary decision to be made, with the frequency being a less important decision that could be changed (or not) by the user.

Comment: The Setting would probably be OFF by default but i absolutely understand where you're coming from.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely make it a separate button. User should NOT have to open up the dropdown to see the option to not be subscribed. Also, consider:

- labeling the ON/OFF toggle... would further enhance clarity
- putting toggle closer to frequency dropdown (see [Gestalt principle of proximity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_of_grouping#Proximity)) ... they're too far apart in your current design, IMO
- toggle should perhaps be to the left of the dropdown, not to the right, to match most users' mental models in terms of what comes first (i.e., user will think about whether or not they want to be subscribed BEFORE they think about frequency, probably)